# The requested resource is not available Tomcat 8.0

Tags: java, intellij-idea, servlet, tomcat, rest

Пытаюсь разобраться немного в сервлетах, нужно написать restful приложение, по примерам все понятно что писать, но видимо я где то упустил небольшую деталь, Idea говорит что артефакт задеплоен а по пути найти его не могу. Если верно понял, путь должен быть: localhost:8080/Project_name/url-pattern/Path  По этому пути получаю постоянно 404 ошибку "The requested resource is not available."
помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.rest.dev.helloWorld</param-value>
    </init-param>

</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Сам код на ужас простейший

```
package com.rest.dev;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
@Path("/hi")
public class helloWorld {
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String sayHello() {
    return "Hello World!";}}
```

pom.xml
выглядит вот так

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jax-rs-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: В логах томката случайно нет урла куда задеплоилось? Вручную пробовали деплоить, без Idea? Если вы деплоите project.war, то по идее у вас урл должен быть localhost:8080/project/rest/hi